# How to get a UK visa while also travelling as a Chinese citizen

Tags: visas, uk, germany, chinese-citizens

I am a Chinese citizen, and I currently live and work in Germany. I have been invited for a job interview in the UK on the 21st of July. Unfortunately I need to get a UK visa to travel there, and I also need to travel for work to Denmark from 7–11 July (I already have a visa which covers the Denmark trip).  This means I can't submit my passport to get the UK visa until 14 July as I will need my passport to get to Denmark.

I see on [www.gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/government/world-location-news/changes-to-uk-visa-application-process-in-germany) that there is now a service called "Passport pass back", but it doesn't explain clearly what this means. Would that work for me, or is there some other solution? I already asked my prospective employer if they can change the interview dates, but they said no.

---

Apparently "pass back" doesn't actually exist yet in Germany so that option is out.

Comment: In theory I believe you may be required to carry your passport while you travel to Denmark, but if you are going overland it's very unlikely that anyone will check (if you're flying the airline might). In practice, you would probably get away with just carrying a German residence card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a passport to travel from Germany to Denmark, since both are in the Schengen region.  In fact, I'm a little confused by why you say have a "visa that covers the Denmark trip", because you really shouldn't need one...?

Denmark also [does not require](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_identity_card_policies_by_country) you to carry identification, although I would recommend taking your German *Personalausweis* (ID card) with you anyway.

Comment: Yes, right. I just was trying to explain that the Danish part is not the problem. The problem is getting to the UK for the job interview.

Comment: You don't need to take your passport to Denmark, since there are no border controls between Germany and Denmark!  So just apply for the UK visa now.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a German residence card. My visa is just for a very long time.

Comment: @felix and can't you get a residence card?