# Can a Blue card holder in Germany travel to UK as dependent?

Tags: visas, uk, germany

My wife is working in UK (with a Tier-2 ICT long term) and I am working in Germany with a Blue card. Both of us are non-EU nationals. (India to be specific). If I wish to visit my wife in week-ends which visa option is the best way? Should I apply for a dependent visa or a tourist visa to enter UK? If I need to apply for travel visa, should I visit my home country (India) to get the visa or can I get in Germany itself?

Comment: This seems like several questions.  The easiest one to answer is that you can apply for a UK visa from Germany.  (See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31413/how-to-get-a-uk-visa-while-also-travelling-as-a-chinese-citizen )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are an Indian national working in Germany, you will need a visa to visit the UK.  Your question is about *which programme* is appropriate: dependent or visitor.

Based upon what you wrote, they would see that you are reliant upon a job in Germany and hence getting a dependent visa would be difficult, especially since your objective is to visit your spouse in your free time.

So you should apply for a visitor visa using the gateway at [visa4UK](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome).  You can enrol your biometrics at the nearest facility in Germany and your application will be processed in Croydon or Paris. They need your passport for about 10 days maximum.

For your other question:  You do not have to return to India to apply for a UK visit visa.

Your wife is on an ICT in the UK and thus does not qualify as a family sponsor.  So you can fill out the form like this......

[image]

And note this advice for people applying in Germany...

[image]